# How to do exact pattern match in query string

Tags: php, mysql, sql, regex

I have my website where I want to add search functionality for the user. My search criteria is `First name` and `last Name` with two different column in mysql databse.

**eg:** If user has entered xxx *(First name)* yyy *(last Name)* in search box then the result is like:

1. If exact match with this two string then only one result has to come
   from database.
2. If doesn't match then simply contain in from database has to come. *(eg
   xx is present then it has to come)*

I've used the following query:

```
Select * from  mytable where FirstName like '%".$fname."%' or LastName like '%".$lname."%' order by DtLastModified desc
```

it is giving me all the result which matches this string.

**eg:**

> xxx yyy
>
> xx  yy
>
> x   y
>
> x
>
> y

Can any one please help me on this.

Comment: show some code have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may work, replace your php variables for $fname $lname

```
SELECT * FROM mytable
WHERE CONCAT(firstname, '', lastname) LIKE '%".$fname.$lname."%' 
OR (firstname LIKE '%".$fname ."%' OR lastname LIKE '%". $lname ."%')
```

Answer (score 0):

**For :**  if exact match with this two string then only one result has to come from database
replace your query  from 'or' to 'and' lik below

```
Select * from  mytable where FirstName like '%".$fname."%' and LastName like '%".$lname."%' order by DtLastModified desc
```